# How to limit web access by password and IP address using .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

We're trying to lock down our administrative site by requiring a password AND requiring that the request is coming from an authorized IP address.  We've figured out how to do both separately, but can't figure out how to combine the two.

```
AuthName     "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /usr/www/users/directory/.passwd
AuthType     Basic
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 79\.1\.129\.85
Satisfy Any
```

This is the closest we've come.  BTW, we also want to be able to enter multiple IP addresses on the white list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
Satisfy All
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#satisfy

As for the Allow from part, have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html

You can use for example

```
Allow from 192.168.1.104 192.168.1.205
```